# How to get access to template generated element wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to get access to TextBox named NameTextBox from my code below (element generated by template) in my xaml.cs file. Especially I want to get Text property. I want this property because want to identify the group after generation.

```c#
<DataGrid x:Name="PersonDataGrid">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <CheckBox x:Name="SelectGroupCheckBox" Checked="SelectGroupCheckBox_Checked"/>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
```

Or If you guys have other idea how to identify specific generated group.
[After generation it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lgZb.png).
I want it because i want to if i check the group header checkbox has checked children checkboxes.

Comment: Please clarify why exactly you want to do that and from where in your code or XAML you think you need that access. Since you are binding the Text property to a Name property in a view model, you would usually access the view model property instead of the view property.

Comment: Whether it explains enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change 
CheckBox code

```
<CheckBox x:Name="SelectGroupCheckBox" 
              Content="{Binding Name}"
              Checked="SelectGroupCheckBox_Checked"
              Unchecked="SelectGroupCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

And in code behind

```c#
private void SelectGroupCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            checkBox.Content.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml.cs file, you just need to use:

```
NameTextBox.Text
```

But it seem's that you are using MVVM mode, in the ViewModel you just need to use the variable that you are binding:

```
Name
```

Comment: I can't do this like that.

Comment: I think it cus this is template element.